# Why 'Segmentation fault' occurs in my cpython module code? (PyObject_Print)

Tags: cpython

I am trying to print PyObject and 'Segmentation fault' occured.
I want to use PyObject_Print.
How can I solve the problem?

```
int main(){
    Py_Initialize();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    PyObject *tmp1 = PyLong_FromLong((1<<29)*3);
    PyObject *tmp2 = PyLong_FromLong((1<<20)*41+1264);
    PyObject *u;
    u = PyNumber_Multiply(tmp1,tmp2);
    PyObject_Print(u,stdout,Py_PRINT_RAW); // Segmentation fault here

    const char* uu = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_Repr(u));
    printf("%s\n", uu); // it works
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I am debugging with vscode.

My tasks.json is

```
       {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/include",
                "-L",
                "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/libs",
                "-lpython37",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
```

I redownloaded whole python3.7 and it did not help
I tried python3.11 cpython in anaconda, and it still 'Segmentation fault' occured.

### Edit

I found python3.10.10 in mingw64. I changed my local python version to 3.10.10. However, still I have an error.

message:
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
ntdll!TpWorkOnBehalfClearTicket () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

I guess the detail error was different from python3.7

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is *u*?

Comment: PyObject *u; was omitted. I changed main function, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Python* is built on *Win* using (native) *VStudio*, so **this configuration (*MinGW*) is unsupported**. Some references:

- [[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)
- [[ReadTheDocs.PythonDev]: Compile CPython on Windows](https://pythondev.readthedocs.io/windows.html#compile-cpython-on-windows)
- [[SO]: setup python 3 in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43301577/4788546)
- [[SO]: Why qt project can throw errors like undefined reference to `__imp_ Py_Initialize' and so on? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72080330/4788546)

I tried reproducing the behavior in several environments.

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>


int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *tmp1 = PyLong_FromLong((1 << 29) * 3);
    PyObject *tmp2 = PyLong_FromLong((1 << 20) * 41 + 1264);
    PyObject *prod = PyNumber_Multiply(tmp1, tmp2);
    const char *prods = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_Repr(prod));

    printf("printf: %s\n", prods);
    printf("Before PyObject_Print\n");
#if defined FILE_NAME
    FILE *fo = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
#else
    FILE *fo = stdout;
#endif
    PyObject_Print(prod, fo, Py_PRINT_RAW);
#if defined FILE_NAME
    fclose(fo);
#endif
    printf("\nAfter PyObject_Print\n");

    Py_Finalize();
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I used *Python 3.10* (where possible).

**Outputs**:

1. *MinGW*:

   > ```bat
   > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076148413]> sopr.bat
   > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
   >
   > [prompt]> "f:\Install\pc064\MinGW\MinGW-W64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw-w64.bat"
   >
   > [prompt]> echo off
   > Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2913]
   > (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
   >
   > [prompt]> md mgwgcc
   >
   > [prompt]> cd mgwgcc
   >
   > [prompt]>
   > [prompt]> gcc -g ..\main00.c -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include -Lc:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs -lpython310 -o pc064_py0310.exe
   >
   > [prompt]>
   > [prompt]> pc064_py0310.exe
   >
   > [prompt]>
   > [prompt]> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10
   >
   > [prompt]> pc064_py0310.exe
   > printf: 69244880085319680
   > Before PyObject_Print
   > :: ------- @TODO - cfati: Crashed here -------
   > ```
2. *VStudio*:

   > ```bat
   > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076148413]> sopr.bat
   > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
   >
   > [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
   >
   > [prompt]> md vs
   >
   > [prompt]> cd vs
   >
   > [prompt]> cl -nologo ..\main00.c -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include  -link -NOLOGO -LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs python310.lib -OUT:pc064_py0310.exe
   > main00.c
   >
   > [prompt]>
   > [prompt]> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10
   >
   > [prompt]> pc064_py0310.exe
   > printf: 69244880085319680
   > Before PyObject_Print
   > 69244880085319680
   > After PyObject_Print
   >
   > Done.
   > ```
3. *WSL*:

   > ```bash
   > (py_pc064_03.10_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076148413]> ~/sopr.sh
   > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
   >
   > [064bit prompt]> uname -a
   > Linux cfati-5510-0 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   > [064bit prompt]> md wslgcc
   > [064bit prompt]> cd wslgcc
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> gcc -g ../main00.c -I/usr/include/python3.10 -L/usr/lib/python3.10 -lpython3.10 -o pc064_py0310
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> ./pc064_py0310
   > printf: 69244880085319680
   > Before PyObject_Print
   > 69244880085319680
   > After PyObject_Print
   >
   > Done.
   > ```
4. *MSYS2*:

   > ```bash
   > [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076148413]> ~/sopr.sh
   > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
   >
   > [064bit prompt]> uname -a
   > MSYS_NT-10.0-19045 cfati-5510-0 3.4.6.x86_64 2023-04-01 11:43 UTC x86_64 Msys
   > [064bit prompt]> md msysgcc
   > [064bit prompt]> cd msysgcc
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> gcc -g ../main00.c -I/usr/include/python3.11 -L/usr/lib/python3.11 -lpython3.11 -o pc064_py0311
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> ./pc064_py0311.exe
   > printf: 69244880085319680
   > Before PyObject_Print
   > 69244880085319680
   > After PyObject_Print
   >
   > Done.
   >
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> gcc -g ../main00.c -I/c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.11/include -L/c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.11/libs -lpython3.11 -o pc064_py0311win  In file included from /c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.11/include/Python.h:38,
   >                  from ../main00.c:2:
   > /c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.11/include/pyport.h:601:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
   >   601 | #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
   > ```
5. *Cygwin*:

   > ```bash
   > [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076148413]> ~/sopr.sh
   > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
   >
   > [064bit prompt]> uname -a
   > CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045 cfati-5510-0 3.4.6-1.x86_64 2023-02-14 13:23 UTC x86_64 Cygwin
   > [064bit prompt]> md cyggcc
   > [064bit prompt]> cd cyggcc
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> gcc -g ../main00.c -I/usr/include/python3.9 -L/usr/lib/python3.9 -lpython3.9 -o pc064_py0309
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> ./pc064_py0309
   > printf: 69244880085319680
   > Before PyObject_Print
   > 69244880085319680
   > After PyObject_Print
   >
   > Done.
   >
   > [064bit prompt]>
   > [064bit prompt]> gcc -g ../main00.c -I/cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.09/include -L/cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.09/libs -lpython3.9 -o pc064_py0309win
   > In file included from /cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.09/include/Python.h:50,
   >                  from ../main00.c:2:
   > /cygdrive/c/Install/pc064/Python/Python/03.09/include/pyport.h:741:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
   >   741 | #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
   >       |  ^~~~~
   > # ----- @TODO - cfati: Truncated some lines ----
   > ```

As seen, "regular" configurations work. In the last 2 examples, trying to use the native *Python* doesn't even compile.
I didn't attempt any debugging, and I'm not going to. You should **stick with officially supported configurations**, pick whichever suits you best. I'd go with the official one (*VStudio*), here are some examples:

- [[SO]: Calling Python function with parametrs from C++ project (Visual Studio) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972756/4788546)
- [[SO]: I then use python to generate dll, c for debugging , after I generate the dll from VS, I am using LoadLibraryA will report error code 1411 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75509710/4788546)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print an object, you can use a workaround:
extract the built-in `print` method and call it directly.

```
void print_object(PyObject* object) {
    // PyEval_GetBuiltins - borrowed reference, PyMapping_GetItemString - new reference
    static PyObject* printer = PyMapping_GetItemString(PyEval_GetBuiltins(), "print");

    auto tuple = PyTuple_New(1);
    Py_INCREF(object);
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tuple, 0, object);
    PyObject_Call(printer, tuple, NULL);
    Py_XDECREF(tuple);
}
```

static to speed up

Or with PyObject_CallOneArg (not tested):

```
void print_object(PyObject* object) {
    static PyObject* printer = PyMapping_GetItemString(PyEval_GetBuiltins(), "print");
    PyObject_CallOneArg(printer, object);
}
```

In my examples, there is no deletion of the object as a result of the function call.